# In a group, does $[G:H] \leq |N|$ always imply $[G:N] \leq|H|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ and $N$ be subgroups of $G$. Suppose that $[G:H] \leq |N|$. Does this always imply that $[G:N] \leq |H|\ $? Lagrange's theorem tells us that this is true in the finite case. What about in general?

Comment: Umm, no.  Take $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, $H$ the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor, and $N$ infinite cyclic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't hold in general. For example Consider $G =Z \times C_2=\langle a,b\rangle$.
We take $H = \langle a^4\rangle$ and $N = \langle b\rangle$, so that
$|G| = |H| = |G:N| = \aleph_0$, while
$|G:H| = 4 \not\le |N| = 2$.

Comment: Generally it is polite to credit the person who actually gave the answer, especially if you copy-paste it: John Bray in this case.